# AssertEquals on sorted lists always returning false

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to write a unit test to test the sorting of two lists.  What I have is I am calling the custom sorting comparator and then comparing the original list with the sorted list.  Then from that I am using assertEquals to test whether the sorted list and original list match.

Let's say I have a simple model... patients.

Patient has two fields... name and age.

```
List<Patient> unOrdered = new ArrayList<Patient>();
List<Patient> ordered = new ArrayList<Patient>();
```

I fill these two up with the same three patients and order the ordered one properly.

```
ordered.add(new Patient("Chris Bacon", "45"));
ordered.add(new Patient("Charles Steak", "82"));
ordered.add(new Patient("Matt Pork", "32"));
```

Then I fill up the ordered one and order by age ascending.

```
unOrdered.add(new Patient("Matt Pork", "32"));
unOrdered.add(new Patient("Chris Bacon", "45"));
unOrdered.add(new Patient("Charles Steak", "82"));
```

So then, in my unit test, I write a Collections.sort with a custom comparator to order the unOrdered list by age ascending.  I print that list out to the console during the test (for me) and then do...

```
assertEquals(ordered, unOrdered);
```

The console prints these lists out in identical order but the assertEquals returns false.  I have even tried creating two completely identical lists in identical orders and trying assertEquals and it still returns false.

I am no Java expert but from what I have read online and the documentation assertEquals is not only checking for equality in the objects in the list but also the order of the objects.  So... why is it always returning false?  Is it that assertEquals cannot handle more complex objects or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does `Patient` have an `equals` method? If not, it will be using the default identity-based equality, and you put different instances in the two lists.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I did have an equals method but I didn't think about checking there.  The issue was there, of course.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the two lists to be considered equal, each element of one list has to compare equal to the corresponding element of the other, so this test is totally dependent on the implementation of the `Patient` equals method.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing lists you it is basically up to the implementation of the `List` how it will be executed. However, for most lists you simply iterate all elements and compare the elements one by one by using the `equals` method. So, in your case you need to provide an `equals` method for the `Patient` class. And, as always - also provide a `hashCode` implementation (it is considered best practice).

Something like this (if you are using Java 8):

```
public class Patient {
    private final String age;
    private final String name;

    public Patient(final String name, final String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Patient) {
            Patient other = (Patient) o;
            return Objects.equals(getName(), other.getName()) && Objects.equals(getAge(), other.getAge());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getName(), getAge());
    }
}
```

On a side note, I would not recommend using a `String` as `age` since. Consider sorting the ages `"2"` or `"10"`. The string value `"10"` comes before `"2"` and that is probably not the intention.

Furtermore, to sort your `Patient` objects you can use some nifty Java 8 features like this:

```
// An unordered list of all patients
List<Patient> allPatients = Arrays.asList(
        new Patient("Matt Pork", "32"),
        new Patient("Chris Bacon", "45"),
        new Patient("Charles Steak", "82")
);

// Sort by name
List<Patient> sortedByName = allPatients.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Patient::getName))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Sort by age
List<Patient> sortedByAge = allPatients.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Patient::getAge))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that you do not actually sort the underlying `List`, you simply create a new `List` with the correct order.

You can read more about Java 8 Streams in [this excellent tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) which covers sorting, filtering etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this demo code, it can run without error. Compare it with yours and find the problem.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

class Patient {
    private String name;
    private String age;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param name
     * @param age
     */
    public Patient(String name, String age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    /**
     * This is the override of super method.
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((age == null) ? 0 : age.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }


    /**
     * This is the override of super method.
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Patient other = (Patient) obj;
        if (age == null) {
            if (other.age != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!age.equals(other.age))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the age
     */
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    /**
     * @param age the age to set
     */
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest {

    /**
     * Rigourous Test :-)
     */
    @Test
    public void testApp() {
        List<Patient> unOrdered = new ArrayList<Patient>();
        List<Patient> ordered = new ArrayList<Patient>();

        ordered.add(new Patient("Charles Steak", "82"));
        ordered.add(new Patient("Chris Bacon", "45"));
        ordered.add(new Patient("Matt Pork", "32"));

        unOrdered.add(new Patient("Matt Pork", "32"));
        unOrdered.add(new Patient("Chris Bacon", "45"));
        unOrdered.add(new Patient("Charles Steak", "82"));

        Collections.sort(unOrdered, new Comparator<Patient>(){

            /**
             * This method is just for demo. Not well defined.
             *
             * @param o1
             * @param o2
             * @return
             */
            @Override
            public int compare(Patient o1, Patient o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }});

        assertEquals(ordered, unOrdered);
    }
}
```